# Jasper Report Saving as PDF

Tags: jasper-reports

Using iReport 3.7.5, I preview Jasper Report and  i wanted save it as PDF file.
PDF file is created but bold and italic formatting are missing on PDF file.

Please how can save correct PDF file.

Comment: Please any answer for this.

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550735/ireport-and-jasperreport-fonts-for-a-pdf-report/ basically you need to include the fonts...

Answer (score 0):

I was faced this problem and I have solved this. It happens due to the Fonts that we are using. If the selected font is not available at Browser or OS then it will throw an Exception of PDF file will be created without Text Formating. You have to make a jar of selected Font using iReport tool. And when you are going to use that application will use font.jar file automatically. And you will get the proper formating of the report.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late but I hope it helps someone who goes through the same thing, you need to include the fonts, if you use maven add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.16.0</version>
</dependency>
```